# Generate ast from constituent elements without using ast.parse in python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Using the python `ast` module, it is possible to generate a simple abstract syntax tree as follows:

```
import ast
module = ast.parse('x=3')
```

This generates a `Module` object for which the source code can be retrieved using the `astor` library as follows:

```
import astor
astor.to_source(module)
```

Generating an output of

```
'x = 3\n'
```

Is it possible to constitute the exact same module object from its constituent elements without using the `ast.parse` method such that the `astor.to_source` method can generate the same source code? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just found it. using `ast.dump` one can inspect the contents of the tree as follows:

```
import astor, ast
module = ast.parse('x=3')
ast.dump(module)
```

This results in the following output which reveals the underlying structure:

```
"Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='x', ctx=Store())], value=Num(n=3))])"
```

We can make use of this information to build the same tree from scratch, and then use `astor` to recover the source:

```
module = ast.Module(body=[ast.Assign(targets=[ast.Name(id='x', ctx=ast.Store())], value=ast.Num(n=3))])
astor.to_source(module)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
'x = 3\n'
```

There is one problem however, since executing this new tree results in an error:

```
exec(compile(module, filename='<ast>', mode="exec"))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from stmt

To fix this, line numbers must be added to each node using the `ast.fix_missing_locations` method.